# print wms layer using geoserver print module - features not aligned properly in the output

Tags: geoserver, printing

I have got the pdf output file while printing map using the geoserver print module. The features in the output image is not in position. They are aligned linearly. Is that any spatial reference issue? 
What could be wrong ?
**my layout in config.yaml**

```
layouts:
   Legal:
mainPage:
  pageSize: LEGAL
  items:
    - !map
      width: 400
      height: 300
      name: map


#===========================================================================
A4 portrait:
#===========================================================================
metaData:
  title: '${mapTitle}'
  author: 'MapFish print module'
  subject: 'Simple layout'
  keywords: 'map,print'
  creator: 'MapFish'

titlePage:
  pageSize: A4
  items:
    - !text
      spacingAfter: 150
    - !text
      font: Helvetica
      fontSize: 40
      spacingAfter: 100
      align: center
      text: '${layout}'
    - !image
      maxWidth: 160
      maxHeight: 160
      spacingAfter: 100
      align: center
      url: http://trac.mapfish.org/trac/mapfish/attachment/ticket/3/logo_v8_sphere.svg?format=raw

  footer: &commonFooter
    height: 30
    items:
      - !columns
        config:
          cells:
            - paddingBottom: 5
        items:
          - !text
            backgroundColor: #FF0000
            align: left
            text: a red box
          - !text
            align: right
            text: 'Page ${pageNum}'
          - !image
            align: center
            maxWidth: 100
            maxHeight: 30
            spacingAfter: 200
            url: 'http://geoserver.org/img/geoserver-logo.png'

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
mainPage:
  pageSize: A4
  rotation: true
  #      header:
  #        height: 50
  #        items:
  #          - !text
  #            font: Helvetica
  #            fontSize: 30
  #            align: right
  #            text: '${layout}'
  items:
    - !text
      text: '${mapTitle}'
      fontSize: 30
      spacingAfter: 30
    - !map
      spacingAfter: 30
      width: 440
      height: 483
    - !columns
      # columns can have an absolute position. In that case, they need the 3 following fields:
      absoluteX: 410
      absoluteY: 310
      width: 100
      items:
        - !scalebar
          type: bar
          maxSize: 100
          barBgColor: white
          fontSize: 8
          align: right
    - !text
      text: '${comment}'
      spacingAfter: 30
    - !attributes
      source: data
      spacingAfter: 30
      columnDefs:
        id:
          columnWeight: 2
          header: !text
            text: ID
            backgroundColor: #A0A0A0
          cell: !text
            text: '${id}'
        name:
          columnWeight: 5
          header: !text
            text: Name
            backgroundColor: #A0A0A0
          cell: !columns
            config:
              cells:
                - backgroundColor: '${nameBackgroundColor}'
                  borderWidth: 1
                  borderColor: '${nameBorderColor}'
            items:
              - !text
                text: '${name}'
        icon:
          columnWeight: 2
          header: !text
            text: Symbol
            backgroundColor: #A0A0A0
          cell: !image
            align: center
            maxWidth: 15
            maxHeight: 15
            url: 'http://www.mapfish.org/svn/mapfish/trunk/MapFish/client/mfbase/mapfish/img/${icon}.png'
    - !text
      font: Helvetica
      fontSize: 9
      align: right
      text: '1:${scale} ${now MM.dd.yyyy}'
  footer: *commonFooter
```

and my **spec** is

```
http://host:port/geoserver/pdf/print.pdf?spec={
    "layout": "A4 portrait",
    "srs": "EPSG:4326",
    "units": "m",
    "geodetic": false,
    "outputFilename": "filename",
    "outputFormat": "pdf",
    "mapTitle": "title",
    "comment": "comment",
    "layers": [{
        "type": "WMS",
        "layers": ["layername"],
        "baseURL": "http://host:port/geoserver/workspacename/wms",
        "format": "image/png",
        "version": "1.1.1",
    }],
    "pages": [{
        "center": [0, 0],
        "scale": 50000,
        "dpi": 190,
        "geodetic": false,
    }],
    "legends": [{
        "classes": [{
            "icons": ["full url to the image"],
            "name": "an icon name",
            "iconBeforeName": true
        }],
        "name": "a class name"
    }]
}
```

the wms layer png image from the geoserver is given below
[image]

the output image is below
[image]

Comment: Please give us some clues - what projection is your data in? what projection is the map in? how did you create the map? can you add the request that your client sent to mapfish? what does the map template look like?